# How to access metadata about memory in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I have a workflow that has multiple tasks doing computation that are connected via data edges; such that one task is producing data for another task. Each task is bound to a separate thread. One of these tasks is getting memory from a memory pool, which is recycled by another task that releases that memory.

`MemoryData` is used within the memory pool to store information like where the memory originated (GPU address space/CPU address space) and release rules (indicates when the memory can be recycled).

Task 1 getting memory from pool:

```
std::shared_ptr<MemoryData<Type>> m = memGet<Type>("MemoryManagerName", ruleForReleasingMemory);
// Store the memory to passed along with data
data->setMemory(m);
```

`m` must be passed from task to task within data until it reaches the task that releases it.

Task 2 releasing the memory:

```
std::shared_ptr<MemoryData<Type>> m = data->getMemory();
memRelease("MemoryManagerName", m);
```

What I'm trying to do is change the return type of `memGet` to just return `Type`. Then during release, it can use some method to get the `MemoryData` to recycle the memory. This will allow me to simplify the `Data` representation so I dont have to store the `std::shared_ptr<MemoryData<Type>>`.

So far I have considered two designs:

(1) using pointer arithmetic to use the pointer to the pointer `**`, and calculate the starting address of the `MemoryData` from there.

(2) Create a mapping between the pointer to Type and the pointer to the MemoryData, this will require sending this information to each task, and if I have to add dynamic memory allocation, then this will get a little challenging

Comment: Why the C tag? C is different from C++. choose one

Comment: I'm open to suggestions from either C or C++. I have found doing pointer arithmetic within a struct easier than a class.

Comment: This can't be C language because C doesn't have `std::shared_ptr` or templates.  I recommend removing the C language tag.

Comment: I am willing to alter the design that is presented if there are methods that C could provide. But if it is causing a rift... I dont mind keeping it strictly to C++.

Comment: Seems like you're writing an elaborate memory allocator -- you can use the same trick that `new[]` does when allocating an array, and store extra metadata just before the allocated object. Then, when destroying it, you can fetch it just by backing up the pointer a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no (by default) meta data about memory (and if there is one, it is implementation specific).

You could write your own memory [allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) (above *existing* operating system *primitives* like [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) on Linux, which are also used by `malloc`) and manage that metadata yourself.

You could play tricks on the memory address (e.g. bit-and and right-shift it, casted as some `uintptr_t`, etc) to get the current arena or memory chunk. What I have in mind is that if you have some *arbitrary* `void* p` pointer into something inside a memory zone provided by your allocator, you might use `(uintptr_t)p >> 14`  to get some smaller index into some of your meta-data, etc.

Of course such address bit-processing is processor and operating system specific (it depends upon the page size, and how the OS handles them).

Comment: I currently have an allocator interface that is used to specify the address space to allocate things within the pool, such as `cudaMalloc`. By writing my own memory allocator in the fashion of mmap, how would this manage primitive `double *` for `Type`? Do you have an example of using bit-and and right-shift on the memory to get the memory chunk?

Comment: You won't write a `mmap`-like thing, you would *use* `mmap` in your own allocator

Comment: You can overload the new and delete operators, globally or locally. However overloading globally takes you into winding paths and weed-strewn fields, it's not a quick fix to an address problem.

Comment: So I would be using the MAP_ANONYMOUS option? I will look into this in more detail. I am a little concerned about performance and might have to go a different route and just accept that passing just `Type` will not be sufficient for managing the metadata for the memory. Possibly just providing some nice typedefs to represent the memory data being passed will be a clean option. Such as [alias template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)

Comment: You probably would use `mmap` once in a while, perhaps once per arena allocation (not per object allocation)